# Multiple Evals - Imacros for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, conditional-statements, eval, imacros

I am trying to set a random delay based on the current time with iMacros for Chrome.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
SET delay EVAL("if (\"!NOW:hh\" == '11') '2<SP>+<SP>9'; else \"3<SP>+<SP>8\";")
SET delay EVAL("if (\"!NOW:hh\" == '12') '1<SP>+<SP>10'; else \"3<SP>+<SP>8\";")
SET delay EVAL("if (\"!NOW:hh\" == '13') '0<SP>+<SP>11'; else \"3<SP>+<SP>8\";")

SET hour EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*{{delay}}); randomNumber;")
```

This is not working as it just runs the first eval. Is there any way to combine this into one single line?

TL;DR:

```
if NOW:hh = '11' then '9 + 2'
if NOW:hh = '12' then '10 + 1'
if NOW:hh = '13' then '11 + 0'
else '8 + 3'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use {{ }}.

You can "else if" or "switch" conditional statements: [JavaScript If...Else Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

```
SET delay EVAL("if (\"{{!NOW:hh}}\" == '11') '2<SP>+<SP>9'; else if (\"{{!NOW:hh}}\" == '12') '10<SP>+<SP>1'; else if (\"{{!NOW:hh}}\" == '13') '11<SP>+<SP>0'; else \"3<SP>+<SP>8\";")

PROMPT {{delay}}

SET hour EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*{{delay}}); randomNumber;")

PROMPT {{hour}}
```

> I am trying to set a random delay based on the current time

I don't know why do need so complicated random statements. This seems enough:

```
SET delay("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*{{!NOW:hh}} + 1); randomNumber;")

PROMPT {{delay}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eng.

Yes it's more complicated than it really needs to be. Mostly because I'm using iMacros for Chrome and because of the way the site is made.

I'm targeting divs in a datepicker to specify the hours to delay:


`TAG SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV:nth-of-type(6)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(6)>DIV:nth-of-type({{hour}})"`


Where `DIV:nth-of-type(8) = 6:00`

I am working in a timezone that is 5 hours ahead, so if the local time is 11:00 (6:00) I would not like it to set the delay to 6:00.